# How to add registration and login in a custom modules

Tags: 7, theming, forms

I am creating a multi step form and in a one step i want to add user registration and login forms in as tabs and i have custom module which is uses to load multi step form,my problem is how i add registration and login forms in my page i try with things but didi't work out

```
  function garland_user_bar() {
  global $user;                                                                
  $output = '';

  if (!$user->uid) {                                                           
    $output .= drupal_get_form('user_login_block');                            
  }                                                                            
  else {                                                                       
    $output .= t('<p class="user-info">Hi !user, welcome back.</p>', array('!user' => theme('username', $user))); 

    $output .= theme('item_list', array(
      l(t('Your account'), 'user/'.$user->uid, array('title' => t('Edit your account'))),
      l(t('Sign out'), 'logout')));
  }

  $output = '<div id="user-bar">'.$output.'</div>';
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: `$login_form = `drupal_get_form('user_login')` you need to render the form in output `$output .= drupal_render($login_form)`

Answer (score 1):

You to need render the form element.

Use the following to print the forms:

```
print(drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_register_form')));
print(drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login_block')));
```